# JQ Toggle and STAY highlighted

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

Good Evening. Could anyone please lend a hand?

Struggling with a simple menu script here : http://jsfiddle.net/GrP9D/

Problem : toggle does not work. On clicking the blue Div's, the gray field should toggle.

My question:

1/ What can I do to make the gray div toggle ?

2/ What could be done to have a setup which would indicate to the user which button they have just selected? Such as that the clicked button stays highlighted until another one is clicked.

Thank you, Jan

Answer (score 0):

edit - i also run chrome. here, open notepad and save this as a .html file, make sure you specify utf-8 encoding

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.randomsnippets.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />


<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone)
{
     $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
               $(this).parent().children(":first-child").css('background-color','#00FFFF');
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(600);
               $(this).parent().children(":first-child").css('background-color','#99CCFF');
      }
          }
     });
}</script>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<body>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div name="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div name="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div name="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
​
```

if this doesnt work, there could be a problem with your computer,because this exact copy works for me, run locally.

Comment: @e wagness -Thanks for shining your light. However, what I am trying to find out, is why the grey div's under blue field 2 and 3 do not appear when their respective blue fields are clicked. I found the script here: bit.ly/GM2xAB . Would be great to have your advice.

Comment: I see, I originally thought you were only trying to show/hide the one original visible div, so i was confused by the other hidden ones, and why you were selecting by id. Now I understand. Actually, what you have should work fine, In the upper left hand corner  under "choose framework" change it from "on load" to "no wrap (head)" or (body) and it should work just fine

Comment: @e wagness - Thank you but ah damn, no luck. I am not sure how to proceed but I'll investigate. jan

Comment: are you sure? i just double checked it, make sure you select no wrap (head) and then click RUN of course or nothing will have actually changed

Comment: @jan i just saved this as a raw html file and ran it locally and it also worked

Comment: @e wagness - installed Firefox, thought that would be the origin of trouble, since I run Chrome. Unfortunately still no luck. I really wonder.

Comment: @e wagness - thank you - the grey toggle now works perfect. No idea what I was doing wrong. One thing however: I am afraid we have lost the "selected buton highlighted"-effect somewhere along the way. Do you remember how you achieved that?

Comment: @jan added 2 lines to the script to "highlight" the "buttons". JQuerys travesing made it very easy, hope that helps. you can always change the color to have it highlight however you would like

Comment: @e wagness - thanks - Yet something still is wrong; At some point in the JSfiddle, the color switch worked fine, unfortunately it doesn't anymore now. Would you mind having another look, and putting the lines of code again where they used to be? Not trolling you, just lost.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GrP9D/37/
that should work just fine, i think it is the "choose framework" option that gets messed up, it should be no wrap (head). what lines of code are you referring to?

Comment: @e wagness - thank you- I finally got it working the other day. Thanks for helping. I think I'll take code classes in september! Regards, Jan

Comment: w3schools.com has a great (and free of course) introductory jquery tutorial (as well as a whole lot of other information and tutorials for web based coding)